# Subset with data.table using key in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

So, I've been learning the nuances of `data.table` for approximately a week. I am currently practicing on the `mtcars` dataframe. Converted into a data table as follows:

```
dt<-data.table(mtcars)
```

I want to subset rows where `disp`>300 and `wt`<5. I can do that in **'i'** as follows:

```
dt[disp>300 & wt<5]
```

```
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs AM gear carb
1: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
2: 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
3: 15.5   8  318 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
4: 15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
5: 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
6: 19.2   8  400 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
7: 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
8: 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

However, I'm a bit obsessed with keys right now, so I was trying to do the same using keys.

```
setkeyv(dt,c('disp','wt'))

dt[.(>300,<5)]
```

This gives an error message as: `Error: unexpected '>' in "dt[.(>"`

I tried another method(this didn't require key, so I removed them) which too gave the same error.

```
dt[.(>300,<5),on=.('disp','wt')]
```

`Error: unexpected '>' in "dt[.(>"`

Although I can perform the following without problems as they don't have a logical operator:

Using keys: `dt[.(145,2.77)]`
  Without using keys: `dt[.(145,2.77),on=c('disp','wt')]`

Hence my question is: How to subset rows using key method and also using `on`(doesn't require key) when subset criteria has a logical operator(eg. >,<,>=,<=)?

Thanks in advance to the wonderful community.

Comment: I would be curious to know but I think what you suggest cannot be done and you have to stick with `dt[disp>300 & wt<5]`